# Error instructs to "perform neccesary action (tx recovery/restart)". How is this done?

Tags: neo4j

## Base Install

I have an m1.large Neo4j Server instance on Amazon EC2 which I setup according to the instructions here:
http://www.neo4j.org/develop/ec2

I did not vary from that setup in any way.

It has been working mostly flawlessly for several weeks, with the occasional restart.  However, I was unable to connect to it from my web app this morning (3/13/2013).

## Attempt #1: Restart

Restart via the Neo4j Server instance from the EC2 management console.  After it rebooted my web app seemed to be able to make the initial connection (via Neoid & Neography) so my web app would at least boot.

However all transactions were then failing.  I tried accessing the admin console for Neo4j on port 7474 at webadmin/, and this is the error I see, in particular:

```
javax.transaction.SystemException: TM has encountered some problem, please perform neccesary action (tx recovery/restart)
```

Restarting is not the solution.

**Full error trace for Attempt #1** when accessing web panel: [GIST #1](https://gist.github.com/pboling/5154753).

## Attempt #2: Recovery

I found a [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/neo4j/CBvuMybTRFw/NMIOpBjrIYIJ) that referenced a seemingly related problem, which indicated that starting neo4j in console mode will allow for a full recovery without timing out, so I tried it, with `SEVERE` results, shedding more light on my problem:

It looks like this is the root cause:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unknown xid for identifier 8964
```

**Full error trace for Attempt #2** running `sudo /var/lib/neo4j/bin/neo4j console`: [GIST #2](https://gist.github.com/pboling/5154765)

## Attempt #3: Delete and Start Over

This is pre-production data, so I have the luxury of drastic measures.  I deleted the database and started over.

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db/
sudo sudo /var/lib/neo4j/bin/neo4j start
```

I was able to create about 50k rels & 50k nodes, and then the errors came back after, at most, a few hours.

## Attempt #4: Recovery Again

I stopped the Neo4j server, and loaded it as console - to do recovery.

**Full trace of Attempt #4 recovery**: running `sudo /var/lib/neo4j/bin/neo4j console`: [GIST #3](https://gist.github.com/pboling/5157244)

Recovery worked so I restarted server as daemon.

**Full trace of Attempt #4 starting daemon**: running `sudo /var/lib/neo4j/bin/neo4j start`: [GIST #4](https://gist.github.com/pboling/5157255)

It worked for a few minutes.  And then back to this error again:

```
TM has encountered some problem, please perform neccesary action (tx recovery/restart)
```

Full trace of new error as seen from Neography's attempt to execute a script: [GIST #5](https://gist.github.com/pboling/5157290)

## Debugging

I now think that despite having used the vanilla Neo4j installed as part of following [this guide for an m1.large server](http://www.neo4j.org/develop/ec2), there are some problems with this configuration.  When I [start the server in console mode](https://gist.github.com/pboling/5157244) these are the bothersome things I see:

1. `INFO ... Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]`
2. `INFO ... Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]`
3. `ERROR ... Could not find resource corresponding to [custom-logback.xml]`
4. And this one

   ```
   WARNING! Deprecated configuration options used. See manual for details
   cannot configure writers and searchers individually since they go together
   ```

*Update*: I have filed a [separate issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/625) for these default configuration problems.

Comment: today i have also encountered the same error message `TM has encountered some problem, please perform neccesary action (tx recovery/restart)` when performing folowing cypher query from ./neo4j-shell on a db of 1M nodes and 2M rels: `cypher 1.9 start n=node:node_auto_index('n_id_customer:*') match n--() with n ,count(*) as cnt where cnt>10000  with n match n-[r]-() where Id(r)%10<>1 delete r;`

Comment: I think you should try the restart first.  Then try the recovery by booting Neo4j into console mode.

Comment: Can you please check and share the messages.log from your data/graph.db directory. console.log is the application level server log, the low level db information is in messages.log. Thanks

Comment: I have resolved my problems, and a full history of the fix is here: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-puppet/issues/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the root device running out of space.

I have resolved my problems so here is a full history and explanation of the fix:
http://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-puppet/issues/3